# Print a timer in Python to see how long to run a script

Tags: python

I want to print a timer in the console to optimize my script and see how long it takes to run the script.

Comment: Related https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/info_best_practice.html#time-your-code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of the fastest ways I know:

```
import time

then = time.time() #Time before the operations start

#DO YOUR OPERATIONS HERE

now = time.time() #Time after it finished

print("It took: ", now-then, " seconds")
```

**time.time()** Will give you the current time in seconds.
There are other ways of doing it, but this is one of the best. I have always used this and it gave me no problem at all.